# ¿Un "moro cojo" era un caballo en la California de 1825?

Tags: historia, nombres-propios, animales, geografía

En la California colonial había un cañón: "El cojo", y un rancho: "Moro cojo". No se notan moros residentes y [una leyenda sugiere](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40685/which-lame-moor-was-the-namesake-of-rancho-moro-cojo) que "el moro cojo" no era un hombre moro y cojo, sino un caballo oscuro y cojo. El [DLE sí tiene](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PqZDbAp) un significado que justifique el uso del adjetivo "moro" para aplicar a un caballo, pero en el nombre del rancho no pusieron ese sustantivo, "caballo".

Quiero saber si los californianos llegaron a hablar del caballo con puros adjetivos, sin sustantivo. Fuera de la cuestión de por qué nombrar lugares así, ¿es posible que "el cojo" y "el moro cojo" fueran caballos? Si es que sí, ¿sabríamos si fueran? La ambigüedad me está cargando.

PS. Ya aprendí que "El Cojo" era una persona, jefe Chumash.

Comment: ¿Cómo que el DRAE no tiene significado de *moro* relacionado con los caballos?  La 7.ª acepción es «Dicho de un **caballo** o de una yegua: De pelo negro, con una estrella o mancha blanca en la frente y calzado de una o dos extremidades.»

Comment: gracias @guifa. yo me equivoqué y he redactado la pregunta.

Comment: No es nada raro. Muchos adjetivos referidos a caballos (alazán, percherón...) se han sustantivado. Aunque el DLE no marque *moro* con el *u. t. c. s.*, es bastante razonable pensar que se haya usado a veces como sustantivo con este significado.

Comment: Eso me recordó un libro que me obligaron a leer en el colegio y que odié por eso: [El Moro](http://www.ellibrototal.com/ltotal/ficha.jsp?idLibro=5173) de José Manuel Marroquín. (Sí, acá también trata de un caballo)

Comment: @MauricioMartinez gracias, este dato es el más valoroso que se ha suministrado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre usar "moro" para describir un caballo, ya te ha respondido Carlos.
Yo me voy a centrar en la plausibilidad de que el nombre del caballo fuese "Moro Cojo".

Te voy a poner, como ejemplo, [nombres de toros famosos](http://www.elartetaurino.com/toros%20famosos.html) basados en el color de su pelaje o en sus características físicas:
- **Sedoso**, por la suavidad del pelaje.
- **Desteñido**, por el color claro del pelaje.
- **Harinero**, por el color blanquecino.
- **Barbudo**, por tener pelo largo en el menton.
- **Melenito**, por tener largo el pelo de la cabeza.
- **Bragao**, por tener el vientre de distinto color que el resto del cuerpo.
- **Sordito**, presumiblemente por no oir bien (o por ignorar al criador jeje).
- **Merino**, presumiblemente por tener el pelaje o la nariz parecidas a las de una oveja de raza merina.

Sin buscar mucho, se pueden encontrar [nombres de caballo que siguen los mismos patrones](https://www.noticaballos.com/nombres-de-caballos.html#Otras_opciones):

> Por ejemplo, **el color del pelaje** del animal suele ser un factor clave para designar un nombre. De ahí, que encontremos caballos llamados: **Colorado, Cenizo**, etc. También, **el carácter** del animal suele ayudar mucho en la decisión final, y de ahí surgen nombres como: **Furia, Salvaje, Bravo**...

Creo que, a la vista de lo anterior, a nadie extrañaría que un caballo se llamase "Moro" o "Moro Cojo".

Que el rancho tomase el nombre del caballo, tampoco es algo fuera de lo común, estoy seguro de que puedes encontrar ejemplos similares de ranchos con el nombre propio de una persona o animal.

Comment: Valorizo la montaje de evidencia que presentó.

Answer (score 2):

Es perfectamente posible. Aunque el adjetivo *moro* aplicado a caballos no entró en el DLE hasta 1925, mucho antes ya se usaba en textos escritos. En España tenemos este de 1789:

> *Se vende un caballo moro en el Parador de Zarogoza y Barcelona, el mozo de la Posada dará razon.*
>
> [Diario de Madrid, 15/1/1789](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0005412258&page=4&search=%22caballo%20moro%22&lang=es), página 4.

Y en América tenemos este otro de mediados del siglo XIX:

> *Sabe que López tiene en su poder su caballo moro sin mandárselo, y Quiroga se enfurece con la noticia.*
>
> Domingo Faustino Sarmiento, "Facundo. Civilización y barbarie", 1845-1874 (Argentina).

Por otra parte, se sabe que los caballos eran una parte importante de la vida a principios del siglo XIX en aquella zona, dado que constituían el principal medio de tracción y de locomoción. Luego no sería de extrañar que un rancho pudiera denominarse en función de algún caballo notable (por el motivo que fuera). Y, como [ya ha dicho Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22598/es-posible-que-un-moro-cojo-fuera-un-caballo#comment36235_22598) en los comentarios, los adjetivos referentes a caballos se sustantivan con facilidad.

Comment: Que "moro" como adjetivo describe color, no tengo dudas. En cuanto a la sustantivación de "moro", sólo tenemos reportado que "es bastante razonable". ¿Algún diccionario estará de acuerdo?

Comment: @walen según Gorpik arriba el DLE debe marcarse con "u.t.c.s.", "usado también como sustantivo".